# How to select some rows with specific values and sort them in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a MYSQL database with some columns and rows.
And I want to select some of rows with same value and sum them and then sort them.

for example:

```
Id    data
1     5
2     12 
4     42
2     2
1     3
1     8
4     2
```

something like :
data : (16 id : 1) , (data : 14 id : 2) , (data : 44 id : 4)

for doing this I tried this code :

```
$sql = "SELECT id, SUM(data) AS value_sum FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY value_sum DESC LIMIT 30";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $ids = "";
    $datas = "";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $ids .= $row['p_id'] . '^';
            $datas.= $row['value_sum'] . '^';
        }
    }
```

And it works fine and I can get sum of rows values sorted as `value_sum`.

But my problem is the ids are not sorted and I want to get sorted ids too but the result is not sorted.
I mean in the result i don't know can I get true id for `value_sum`.

for more explanation I want this result :

(id 4 : 44) , (id 1 : 16) , (id 2 : 14)

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can order by as many columns as you like in an order by so I'm not clear what you mean by ' i don't know can I get true id for value_sum.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use sum() ,  group  by and order by sum and id

```
select  id, sum(data) , concat('(id ',id, ':', sum(data) , ')')
from my_table  
group by  id   
order by sum(data) desc, id asc
```

or

```
select  id, sum(data) 
from my_table  
group by  id  
order by id asc, sum(data) desc
```

and if you need  on the same rows

```
select group_concat(my_col) 
from  (
select  id, sum(data) , concat('(id ',id, ':', sum(data) , ')') my_col
from my_table  
group by  id   
order by sum(data) desc, id asc ) t
```

Comment: I tried this but the ids are not match with `value_sum`s

Comment: i mean ids are sorted by rows not with value_sum

Comment: your comments are not clear  .. update  you question add  a clear expected  result  as a tabular result  .. (what mean id are sorted  by rows  not by sum????)

Comment: i update that. i mean this part : id asc , only sorts ids by rows index. but what i want is sorted ids with 'sum(data)' result. @scaisEdge

Comment: answer update  .. based on your sample  (id 4 : 44) , (id 1 : 16) , (id 2 : 14)